# How to show 2 currency signs on same dashboard in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 payment gateways on  my web one for USD and one for bitcoin. 
code is given below. I want if user use USD he  get $ on dashboard amount and if he use bitcoin to add balance then he get B sign with is dashboard balance. currently system is using only 1 sign that is $.

```
<div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 style="font-size: 28px;"><b>
                @if($fund->payment_type == 1)
                    Paypal
                @elseif($fund->payment_type == 2)
                    Perfect Money
                @elseif($fund->payment_type == 3)
                    BTC - ( BlockChain )
                @else
                    Credit Card
                @endif
                </b>
            </h3>
        </div>
```

Comment: Where is `$` sign in this code?

Comment: it is from admin panel named $basic->currency

Comment: I don't see that variable neither in code block above. You posted code that doesn't represent the issue. Edit your question and post appropriate code block responsible for issue in matter.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
{{ $fund->payment_type === 3 ? '₿' : '$' }}{{ $amount }}
```

Comment: can you explain it

Comment: Explain what exactly? If `$fund->payment_type === 3` then bitcoin sign will be shown in the view before the amount. If not, dollar sign will be shown.